# When I try to update the item in a list the item gets updated but the UI doesn't change. I'm using Getx and I have tried update and refresh

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

**This is my Controller**

```
class TicketController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var ticketList = List<Ticket>.empty(growable: true).obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    getAllTickets();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void getAllTickets() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var tickets = await ApiService.getAllTickets();
      if (tickets != null) {
        ticketList.value = tickets;
        ticketList.refresh();
        //ticketList.assignAll(tickets);
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }

  void updateStatus(String status, String id) async {
    try {
      await ApiService.updateTicket(status, id);
      ticketList.refresh(); // I have used refresh method after searching but no difference
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

**I'm trying to update with this line**

```
ticketController.updateStatus("SUCCESS", winner.id.toString());
```

I wrapped my widget with GetBuilder but the updated item in the list doesn't change or is not reactive in the ui. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try using update() function.

Comment: Please user the GetBuilder() instated of Obx() and after the added the items to the list just call the update() method. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

When I was facing the same issues I just deleted the `controller's` data after calling the `API` then it prefetches all the data when we come back to that screen

You can try by doing so

```
  if (tickets != null) {
    ticketList.value = tickets;
    ticketList.refresh();
     Get.delete<TicketController>();
  }
```

Comment: Where do you do this...on your view(UI screen secrion)

Comment: you can place this logic where you're calling the API.